# Forwarding posted file(s)

Tags: asp.net, file, redirect, post

I have 3 asp.net pages... page1, page2 & page3.

Page 1 contains a web form with multiple elements (text boxes, drop down lists etc.) and a single file element to allow users upload a file.  Page 1 submits to page 2.
Page 2 processes the incoming request and, currently using a StringBuilder, constructs a page to submit to page 3.

My question is... how can the file submitted to page 2 be forwarded on to page 3?

My guess is that a StringBuilder won't be able to do what I want and that I need to use something else, but what?

Answer (score 0):

> how can the file submitted to page 2 be forwarded on to page 3?

You don't want to do that, it'll make the requests huge. Just store the files on page 1 in some kind of temporary directory on the server and move them to their final destination on page 3.

Then make sure to regularly clean the temporary directory so you won't end up with tons of files from unfinished signups.

Comment: Sorry CodeCaster - that won't work - security policy means nothing can be written to disk/database by Page 1 or Page 2, but huge requests are acceptable.

Comment: Silly security policy is being silly. Then store the files in the session, or base-64 encoded in hidden fields.